# Usage of Active Voice without subject

Tags: pronouns, passive-voice, active-voice

Is it possible to use active voice, if we don't want to mention the subject.
For example:
Is it possible to convert *"The room was cleaned"* into an active voice statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rule for Passive-to-Active:**

The passive-voice sentence must have a *direct subject*.

e.g.

> "The letter was being mailed by **Marylin**" -> "**Marylin** was mailing the letter", as Marylin is the direct subject in the passive-voice sentence.
>
> whereas,
>
> "The room was being cleaned" cannot be converted to an active voice as there is no direct subject.

**Rule for Active-to-Passive:**

The active-voice sentence must have a *direct object*.

e.g.

> "The man is eating **burgers**." -> "**Burgers** are being eaten by the man", as Burger is the direct object in the active-voice sentence.
>
> whereas,
>
> "Parrots live in the rainforest" cannot be converted to a passive voice as there is no direct object.

Comment: What about "The rainforest is populated (lived in) by parrots" ?

Comment: You can turn OP's sentence into the passive by introducing a dummy grammatical subject : "Someone cleaned the room" is correct and answers the purpose of not expressing the real subject.

Comment: @Laure: I agree with your suggestions. But my answer is based on the assumption that OP wants to change the voice of the sentence without changing the semantics of it in any way (or to simplify it, by using the exact same words and subjects/objects). By introducing "a dummy object" (someone) or replacing a word by another (eg. 'live' by 'populated') does changes the meaning of sentence.

Comment: There are a few grammatical mistakes in the given examples that may confuse users (like the OP).  I've put in an edit to at least make it passable, but am concerned about altering the meaning to make more edits.  I'd suggest reviewing your answer to make sure the grammar cannot be further improved.

Comment: @Doc: your edit approved.

Answer (score 5):

To turn your sentence into an active voice you need to introduce a grammatical subject. If you do not want to name the subject you can use a dummy subject such as "someone".

> Someone cleaned the room.

Comment: Also called as **indefinite pronoun.**

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

Here are a couple examples of short passives from *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*, p.243:

> **Passive**: *Mistakes were made.*
> **Active**: **Made mistakes.*
>
> **Passive**: *Your car was damaged.*
> **Active**: **Damaged your car.*

The passive allows you to avoid saying who made mistakes or who damaged the listener's car.
The active does not; it requires a main clause subject, so the active counterparts are ungrammatical.

You can, of course, come up with a similar-looking sentence with the same meaning by supplying a grammatical subject (as in Laure's answer), but then you no longer have an active voice counterpart; you have a slightly different sentence.

Answer (score 1):

To turn your sentence into an active voice when the subject is not given, you need to introduce a grammatical subject.

If you do not want to name the subject you can use a dummy subject such as "**someone**" or "**somebody**".

There can two answers:

1. **Someone** cleaned the room.

or:

2. **Somebody** cleaned the room.